# document.getElementById(id) where id is variable

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I would like your assistance with some functions I'm trying to develop. The code I'm working with:

```
function ApplyModificationDate (){
var results;
var today;
var moddatestable;
var arrayID;
results = getIframeTableContent('reportresults');

var arrayID = [100,101,102,103,104,105,106];

for(var i=0;i<arrayID.length;i++){
    if(arrayID[i]==results[i][1])

     document.getElementById(arrayID[i]).innerHTML = results[i][1];
 }
}
```

The getIframeTableContent is a function that collects the data from an iframe and works fine.

The results is an array of two columns.The 1st column has the ids and the 2nd the last modification date for each id.
I want to check the id's of the arrayID with results values and appear the date, however there is an error in IE console and the dates are not appearing( Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined).

With The second function i want  to check whether the date is older than 7 days from today .In that case i would like date to become bold.Again i tried with the following function but doesn't work.

```
function CheckModDate(){

    today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;


    moddatestable = [100,101,102,103,104,105,106];
    for(var i=0;i<moddatestable.length;i++){

        if((today - document.getElementById(moddatestable[i]).innerHTML)<=7)
        document.getElementById(moddatestable[i]).innerHTML.style.fontWeight =      'bold';
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome ,
Thank you

Comment: i see at least two errors: `document.getElementById(i)` you try get element no by id from array, but simple counter, and second: `arrayID[i]=results[i][1]` assigning instead of comparing

Comment: Im a beginner at javascript. Thanks for this . I made the changes however again the error  Unable to get value of the property '1': object is null or undefined 
 appears . i updated  here the code accordingly

Comment: if you have `Unable to get value of the property '1':` so something wrong with your `getIframeTableContent` function, can you provide it? can you provide sample on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: well thanks,i had one more element in one array, i aligned them and now works fine. The issue with style conversion remains.I want last week elements to become bold

Comment: just skip _innerHTML_ and all should work. also _innerHTML_ and your _today_ is **string**, so `today - document.getElementById(moddatestable[i]).innerHTML` always _NaN_, and _NaN_ always _<=7_

Comment: Shall i use parseInt?

Comment: methinks you rather need [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) if you want work with date

Comment: Well thanks but the problem is that Date.parse() does not work in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.Im stucked

Comment: you can use 3rd party lib for parsing date, like _moment.js_

Comment: Thanks a lot , i managed to fixed it.Because of testing with console.log i had declared today var as global and apparently the same var name was used  already and caused the inaccurate results! .Thank you all,especially @Grundy,  for your asssistance

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you aren't actually using the ID found in your array. Consider this example.

```
var arrayID = [100,101,102,103,104,105,106];

for(var i=0; i < arrayID.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(arrayID[i]);
}
```

The output will be the following

```
0
100
1
101
...
```

To actually use the ID found in the array.

```
var arrayID = [100,101,102,103,104,105,106];

for(var i=0; i < arrayID.length; i++){
    var elem = document.getElementById( arrayID[i] );
    // do stuff with elem
}
```

Comment: for(var i=0;i<arrayID.length;i++){
 var elem = document.getElementById(arrayID[i]);
  if(results[i][1]==elem){

    elem.innerHTML = results[i][1];
  }
 }
}